# how can I swap two records in sql server with script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want swap two records in sql server for example

[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `update table set id = 3-id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one statement with `JOIN` like this

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.id = t2.id
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON (t1.id = 1 AND t2.id = 2)
    OR (t1.id = 2 AND t2.id = 1)
```

Output after update:

```
| ID | NAME | FAMILY |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 | Mary | Simson |
|  2 | Jame |  Ander |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/837b2/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *,CASE WHEN id=123 then 987 ELSE 123 END AS JoinId
    INTO #Temp
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ID in (123,987)

--swap values
UPDATE y
    SET col1=t.col1
        ,col2=t.col2
    FROM YourTable        y
        INNER JOIN #Temp  t ON y.id =t.JoinId
    WHERE ID in (123,987)
```

Comment: you should surround this inside a transaction, or otherwise you could mess up things :)

Answer (score 0):

in the case that ID is `identity` you could  use a combined solution between @Vaibs_Cool and @user814064

something like this

```
DECLARE @aID INT, @bID INT
SELECT @aID = 123, @bID = 987

;WITH ToSwap AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN id = @aID THEN @bID ELSE @aID END AS id, [Name], [Family]
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE id IN (@aID, @bID)
)
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Name]=ToSwap.[Name], [Family] = ToSwap.[Family]
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN   ToSwap  ON YourTable.id =ToSwap.Id
```